# Is the "underworld" map in Terranigma accurate with the storyline?

Tags: terranigma

Something bothers me about the depiction of the "underworld" in Terranigma.

So in the dialog of the game, the world is described as a hollow sphere wherein the underside is the "under world" and the outer side is the "surface world".  This is backed up by the part of the storyline where you go from the under world to the surface world by jumping through a big hole in the ground (or "portal").  The above description would look something like this:
[image: Terranigma diagram 1]

However when you leave Crysta early in the game, the world map is depicted thus:
[image: Terranigma screenie]

It clearly looks like you are walking on the inside face of an *outer* sphere, with there being two concentric spheres, and the internal one shows the oceans of the 'surface world'.  In such a setup, things would look more like this:
[image: Terranigma diagram 2]

So which structure is correct?  Did the graphics people just screw up the look of the under world map at the beginning of the game or am I misunderstanding about the structure of the world?  :-)

Comment: I think design number 1 but the blue "ceiling" you see when underworld is the earth core.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the "glass ceiling" that you see in the underworld is the sun of the underwold, called the Ragnara stone (this is where you fight Dark Gaia at the end). So in your first picture, in the middle of the "under world" or "inner world", you would need to insert the Ragnara stone as a third circle.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the blue "ceiling" carefully as you scroll the underworld map screen, you will realise it's not the oceans. Maybe it's supposed to be, but it's actually just a reflection of the ground. You can verify this by watching a magma river or pool, and scrolling up or down. The distorted shape of the magma will be visible up above, reflecting from the ground as it scrolls past the bottom of the screen.

Note that this means nothing. It's just the way it's drawn, nothing more. If it's meant to be the surface oceans, this does not disprove that theory. Assuming it is meant to be the oceans, if it was accurate, the game would have to do a lot more work drawing the underworld map screen. The way things are, a distorted, recoloured reflection is far less intensive. Otherwise the game would have to reference both maps while on the underworld map screen instead of just one; it might cause major slowdown depending on various factors. But a reflection means the game need not have anything to do with the surface map at that point. Less stuff to reference, less calculations and stuff to do while preparing to plot stuff to the screen, etc.

I believe the correct theoretical model for the Terranigma world is a hollow sphere, where the underworld is on the inner side of the surface. The "sun" if there is one (I forget the details) would be the core, or the Gaia force or something, depending on whether we're talking physics or magical planetary life force stuff (like in the Final Fantasy film).

I have put a lot of deep thought into Terranigma's mysteries. GameFAQs has a number of my questions, including the likes of "What does the Horn Pin even do?" (No-one knows. It appears to be non-functional.) https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/588784-terranigma